# How to add an extra class (.info) containing text to my js code

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, user-interface, jquery-ui

.info needs to act the same way as .showBorder, meaning will move along with the border but will be placed above the box. A better way to structure this using jQuery is also welcome, all suggestions welcome!

```js
 // Get references to the two sets of boxes
var numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".click");
var letters = document.querySelectorAll(".border");

// Turn each node list into proper arrays:
numbers = Array.prototype.slice.call(numbers);
letters = Array.prototype.slice.call(letters);

// Loop through all the number boxes
numbers.forEach(function(box, index){

  // Set up the click event handlers for all the number boxes
  box.addEventListener("click", function(){
  
    // Remove borders from each of the letter boxes
    letters.forEach(function(box){
      box.classList.remove("showBorder");
      
    });
      
    // Apply the border to only the one clicked element
    letters[index].classList.add("showBorder");
  });
  
});
```

```css
.list-box li {display: inline;list-style-type: none;padding: 1em;background:red;}
.list-box {margin:50px auto;}
.box-sleeve li {display: inline;list-style-type: none;padding: 1em;background:red;}
.box-sleeve {margin:50px auto;}
.showBorder { border: 3px dashed black; }
.info {margin:0;padding:1em;}
```

```html
<section>
        <div class="container">
                   <ul class="list-box">
                       <li class="click">1</li>
                       <li class="click">2</li>
                       <li class="click">3</li>
                       <li class="click">4</li>
                   </ul> 
                <span class="info">paragraph</span>
                   <ul class="box-sleeve">
                       <li class="border">a</li>
                       <li class="border">b</li>
                       <li class="border">c</li>
                       <li class="border">d</li>
                   </ul> 
                </div>
            
    </section>
```

Comment: `above the box` can you please show us manually what it is supposed to look like?

Comment: @Oen44 the text 'paragraph' needs to move along the same as the border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't think of better way to do this, based on code you provided. I hope that you get the idea and can implement that in your project.

## Edit

Paragraph is visible after box is checked.

```js
// Get references to the two sets of boxes
var numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".click");
var letters = document.querySelectorAll(".border");

// Turn each node list into proper arrays:
numbers = Array.prototype.slice.call(numbers);
letters = Array.prototype.slice.call(letters);

// Loop through all the number boxes
numbers.forEach(function(box, index){

  // Set up the click event handlers for all the number boxes
  box.addEventListener("click", function(){
  
    // Remove borders from each of the letter boxes
    letters.forEach(function(box){
      box.classList.remove("showBorder");
    });
      
    // Apply the border to only the one clicked element
    var info = document.getElementsByClassName('info')[0];
    info.style.left = 10+(index*45) + 'px';
    info.style.display = 'inline';
    letters[index].classList.add("showBorder");
  });
  
});
```

```css
.list-box li {display: inline;list-style-type: none;padding: 1em;background:red;}
.list-box {margin:50px auto;}
.box-sleeve li {display: inline;list-style-type: none;padding: 1em;background:red;}
.box-sleeve {margin:50px auto;}
.showBorder { border: 3px dashed black; }
.info {margin:0;padding:1em; position: relative; display: none;}
```

```html
<section>
        <div class="container">
                   <ul class="list-box">
                       <li class="click">1</li>
                       <li class="click">2</li>
                       <li class="click">3</li>
                       <li class="click">4</li>
                   </ul> 
                <span class="info">paragraph</span>
                   <ul class="box-sleeve">
                       <li class="border">a</li>
                       <li class="border">b</li>
                       <li class="border">c</li>
                       <li class="border">d</li>
                   </ul> 
                </div>
            
    </section>
```

Comment: Nearly perfect for what I need but can the the text only show when .showBorder activated?

Comment: perfect, exactly this!